# Horizontal legend in GeoServer but not rotated labels

Tags: geoserver, getlegendgraphic

I am trying to get the legend via GeoServer in horizontal orientation. I use `legend_options=layout:horizontal` but the labels are still in vertical position. Is there a way to rotate also the labels?

url: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/myworkspace/wms?request=GetLegendGraphic&version=1.1.1&format=image%2Fpng&width=20&height=20&layer=mylayer&legend_options=layout:horizontal;fontName:Times%20New%20Roman;fontAntiAliasing:true;fontSize:10&style=T2

[image]

Comment: please show us the legend and the full url you sent

Comment: @Ian Turton, I uploaded and image and my url on my post

Comment: is your layer a raster?

Comment: yes, it's a netcdf

Comment: @Ian Turton is there a difference because it is a raster?

Comment: It seems to work for vector layers, so yes.